# Spring Data JPA 2.0.0: How to best resolve conflict between custom findById method and new version in CrudRepository?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Release 2.0.0 of Spring Data JPA replaced the findOne and exists methods with findById and existsById in CrudRepository.

We have the unfortunate situation where our entities PK attribute are called "oid", and often there is an additional natural id field named "id".  To make matters worse both are Strings.

This means that our existing findById and existsById Repository methods conflict or inadvertently override those in CrudRepository.

The findById we can rename to queryById, and the existsById we can rename to something like existsLocalById, but both are workarounds and I suspect bugs will be introduced by people inadvertently using the wrong method.

Are there any other options available which would result in a cleaner design?

Answer (score 1):

So a little digging into the [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944?focusedCommentId=133645&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-133645) behind the change reveals the following:

> it should work if you annotate the method with @Query as that
>   indicates you want this thing to be a query method explicitly

Initial testing appears to show that this works as expected, e.g. In MyEntityRepository..

```
@Query
Optional<MyEntity> findById(String id);

@Query
boolean existsById(String id);
```

We'll still have to take care that the correct method is used as it could lead to some hard-to-determine bugs I suspect.